# How do I sort an array in NASM?

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, nasm, bubble-sort

I'm posting this because  found this assignment rather difficult, and StackOverflow has helped me countless times. Hopefully this will help someone else out.

Problem Description:

Read in N integers, terminated by a value of zero (zero is not used). Sort these numbers into ascending order and print them out. An error message must be produced if either no data is entered prior to a value of zero, or if too much data is entered and would overflow the array. This program should be able to handle up to 100 integer values.

Approach:

I decided to use a bubble sort, which iterates through each value in the array N times for an array of size N. It looks at each value and compares it to the next value; if the first value is higher than the next, it switches them. this could easily be modified to list them in descending order, as well. Anyway, what was most difficult here was handling a nested loop in nasm, and properly looping with all the ecx values and whatnot. The code I'm posting is well commented. Also, any constructive criticism is welcome, as are questions.

Reflections on this project:

I think there may be a better way to go through elements in the array, rather than using ebx. Masm has a pointer thing that can be used to iterate through the values. This code works and meets the requirements, but it could probably be better. Also, bubble sort may not be the best way to do it. I know there are other sorting algorithms, but bubble seemed the easiest to implement in nasm.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better to include your solution in the question. Now it seemed like the question had already been answered and did not need anymore attention. Lucky you, here are my thoughts about it:

You have to initialize the array with 101 doublewords because you will have stored that many inputs before jumping to the label tooManyInts.
When decrementing ECX you comment it is because of 0-based indexing. This is not true. It's because a series of N elements requires N-1 comparisons.
I find it hard to keep track of what's on the stack. Might I suggest you comment somewhat like this

```
push ecx    ;(1)
dec ecx
push ecx    ;(2)
...
loop L3
pop ecx     ;(2)
SetWrite:
xor ebx,ebx
pop ecx     ;(1)
```

Comment: it does not store the 101st value; upon reading the 101st int, it jumps to toomanyints. it compares ex to 100 before it writes the value to an array. Also, regarding 0 based indexing, I suppose what I meant was [intArray] points to the first value and [intArray + ecx*4] will throw some equivalent of a null pointer exception in the event that ex is the length of the array because if the array has 100 values, the first value is [intArray] whereas the last value is [intArray + 4*99]. But for the bubble sort, I believe you're right regarding the n-1 comparisons.

Comment: And at any point there are no more than two value on the stack: first ecx (the number of values to later be written) is pushed, and then ecx-1 (the number of times the outer loop should execute) is pushed.

Comment: but thank you for the feedback! I did feel that this question was completely answered as it runs as the problem specifies it should. Assembly language is tricky and I was hoping to help any future students, and I've decided to change the comment you pointed out.

Comment: You write **it compares ecx to 100 before it writes the value to an array** . True, but by using JUMP ON GREATER you effectively allow 101 values to pass before going to _toomanyints_ ! Put the compare with EAX before the compare with ECX and use jump on greater or equal on the latter. What you say about that it does not store the 101st value only holds if that value is zero.